# Elastic Search Aggregation with Filter unable to filter aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

Hello We are working on a project and we are stuck at this if someone can help that would be really Great

```
GET xyxz/_search
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "company":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"skills.name.keyword",
            "size":10
         }
      }
   },
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[

         ],
         "filter":[

         ],
         "should":[
            {
               "wildcard":{
                  "skills.name":{
                     "value":"jav*"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not":[

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

NEW UPDATED QUERY

```
                    POST INDEX/_search
                    {
                        "size": 0,
                        "aggs": {
                            "my_terms": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "script": {
                                        "inline": """
                                if(doc['skills.name.keyword'].size()>0)
                                {                   
                                    if(doc['skills.name.keyword'].value.contains("jav"))
                                    {
                                      return doc['skills.name.keyword'];
                                    }
                                }
                              """
                                    },
                                    "size": 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

SAMPLE RESPONSE

```
            {
                "took" : 7469,
                "timed_out" : false,
                "_shards" : {
                    "total" : 1,
                    "successful" : 1,
                    "skipped" : 0,
                    "failed" : 0
                },
                "hits" : {
                    "total" : {
                        "value" : 10000,
                        "relation" : "gte"
                    },
                    "max_score" : null,
                    "hits" : [ ]
                },
                "aggregations" : {
                    "my_terms" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 871,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "java",
                                "doc_count" : 121
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "javascript",
                                "doc_count" : 77
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "sql",
                                "doc_count" : 62
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "core java",
                                "doc_count" : 46
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "xml",
                                "doc_count" : 43
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "software development",
                                "doc_count" : 36
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "requirements analysis",
                                "doc_count" : 34
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "microsoft sql server",
                                "doc_count" : 31
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "java enterprise edition",
                                "doc_count" : 30
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "jquery",
                                "doc_count" : 27
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
```

Message :
I would like to say a big Thanks for helping me out we have been communicating through stack overflow since several weeks.
Thanks once again to the stack overflow community

Comment: hey @soumil, did the below solution resolve your issue? Is there anything else you are looking for!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution: Aggregation Result:

Post receiving your mapping, below is what you are looking for where I've made use of [`Scripted Terms Aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script):

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "inline": """
            if(doc['skills.name.keyword'].size()>0){                    <---- Note this logic I've added 
                if(doc['skills.name.keyword'].value.contains("jav")){
                  return doc['skills.name.keyword'];
                }
            }
          """
        }, 
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've made use of `contains` method of `String` class for Java. You can change the logic according to what you are looking for so that only aggregation values that you'd want could be filtered out.

The reason you may have to filter aggregation response is due to the fact that your sample document can have multiple skills like below sample:

```
{
  "skills": [
    {
      "name": "java"
    },
    {
      "name": "javascript"
    },
    {
      "name": "c++"
    }
    ]
}
```

Note that your solution is of `object` datatype.

*Query result would return the entire document, aggregation query would then run on top of these results.*

So as you can see, the above document also has `c++` and that it would also be included in the aggregation query. The only way to achieve the aggregation on the `hits` is to make use of scripted logic which I've mentioned.

### Autocompete Question:

Second question is autocomplete feature and for that you would need to read a bit about it as there are various ways to achieve it.

However, I'd suggest you to start with understanding [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) phase of Elasticsearch, understand what an [Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html) is and its various parts that constitute Analyzer, finally moving on to reading about [Edge n-grams tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) and [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester).

It will take a while to grasp all these concepts but once you get the hang of it, its relatively easy to have it implemented.

Note that wildcard queries are not something I'd recommend. Once you understand and get to know about Ngram or Edge Ngram tokenizers, your query could be as simple as a simple match query for `jav`. But do read about the concepts mentioned in the links.

Let me know if this helps and if you want any further clarification.

Comment: sure sir thanks you i will read about it mean while i tried your query and its not returning what i am expecting here is a sample output

Comment: {
            "key" : "java",
            "doc_count" : 888510
          },
          {
            "key" : "javascript",
            "doc_count" : 705903
          },
          {
            "key" : "html",
            "doc_count" : 567556
          },
          {
            "key" : "sql",
            "doc_count" : 563172
          },
          {
            "key" : "microsoft office",
            "doc_count" : 437694
          }

Comment: Looking at its name, it looks like `skills.keyword` is an array? Could you please check that and if so, could you please share me a sample document for which both keys with `java` as well as `html` returns.

Comment: do you want the mapping ?

Comment: Yes please, that'd be helpful

Comment: here you go "skills" : {
          "properties" : {
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },

Comment: @SoumilNitinShah Apologies for delay. Could you please check the answer now

Comment: i dont see the answer here can you kindly assist ?

Comment: Check the aggregation query that's mentioned in `Solution: Aggregation Result` part

Comment: Hello Thanks a lot i have run time error can you please help

Comment: Hello sir ! just wanted to let you know that i am still having issue if you can kindly spare some time to help me out

Comment: hey @SoumilNitinShah I completely forgot about this. So sorry. I've mentioned updated query. Could you please test that and let me know if that works.

Comment: Hello sir thanks for getting me back i tried and it didnt worked i have posted the error above can you please have a look at it

Comment: eason": "runtime error",
                    "script_stack": [
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Strings.get(ScriptDocValues.java:496)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Strings.getValue(ScriptDocValues.java:503)",
                        "if(doc['skills.name.keyword'].value.contains(\"jav\")){\r\n              ",
                        "                             ^---- HERE"
                    ],
                    "script": "

Comment: @SoumilNitinShah Strange, could you tell me which ES version is this. ES 5? I've updated the query once again now. Please try that. If it still doesn't work, could you please update the exact query that you've used.

Comment: Any further luck, Soumil?